# Is it possible to apply CSS to a span class withouth name?

Tags: html, css

I'm tryng to change a string of text inside a span class without name, of a wordpress theme of wich i shouldn't change any html/php.

```css
    .text-wrap.car_type span {
      display: none !important;
    }
    .text-wrap.car_type:after {
      content: 'whatever it is you want to add';
    }
```

```html
    <div class="text-wrap car_type">
        <span class="">Car type</span>Catamaran
    </div>
```

Css code just afecting the text (Catamaran) inside the div and not the string  (car type) inside of span as i want.
help please.

Comment: Use visibility hidden on the span and visible on the pseudo element

Comment: Although I would probably go with hiding the child span and then putting a before on the parent